# Redux-saga get data from action returns patternOrChannel is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I need to send dynamic data from my screen to action/reducer and fetch data from API with that data, but when i yield in my **rootSaga** i'll get an error like this:

> uncaught at check take(patternOrChannel): patternOrChannel is undefined
>    uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga
>    at takeEvery
>    Error: take(patternOrChannel): patternOrChannel is undefined

Screen code:

```
import { checkUserLoginStatus, userSignin } from '../actions/user';

class PreCheckout extends PureComponent {
   handleLogin = () => {
     this.props.dispatch(userSignin(username, password));
   };
   render() { .......
```

Action:

```
const USER_SIGNIN = 'USER_SIGNIN';

export const userSignin = (username, password) => ({
   type: USER_SIGNIN,
   username,
   password,
});
```

Reducer:

```
import {
  CHECK_USER_LOGIN_STATUS,
  USER_SIGNIN,
  USER_SIGNIN_RESULT,
  USER_SIGNIN_ERROR,
} from '../actions/user';

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isFetching: false,
  information: {},
  error: null,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHECK_USER_LOGIN_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case USER_SIGNIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case USER_SIGNIN_RESULT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        information: action.result,
      };
    case USER_SIGNIN_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
```

Redux-Saga:

```
import {
  USER_SIGNIN,
  USER_SIGNIN_RESULT,
  USER_SIGNIN_ERROR,
} from '../actions/user';

function* fetchUserInformation(action) {
  try {
    console.log('fetchUserInformation action: ', action);
    const response = yield call(login, action);
    yield put({
      type: USER_SIGNIN_RESULT,
      result: response.result,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({
      type: USER_SIGNIN_ERROR,
      error: e.message,
    });
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(USER_SIGNIN, fetchUserInformation);
}
```

Comment: looks pretty much like some of your constants are undefined, make sure that all of them are defined

Comment: I cannot find any undefined there.

Comment: could you please add the imports in actions / saga / reducer ?

Comment: @JoseAPL I've updated my question with the imports.

Comment: You forgot to export constant `**export** const USER_SIGNIN = 'USER_SIGNIN';` or somewhere below `export { USER_SIGNIN };`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oops!!!! such a big mistake!! Thank you!

Comment: @YuryTarabanko If you post an answer i'll mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I have mention in comment. You simply forgot to export the constant.

Should be

```
export const USER_SIGNIN = 'USER_SIGNIN';
```

Or

```
const USER_SIGNIN = 'USER_SIGNIN';

...

export { USER_SIGNIN };
```

These types of bugs could be captured by `eslint` using `eslint-plugin-import` with this [rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md) enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Probably `USER_SIGNIN` is undefined.

Comment: No, `USER_SIGNIN` imported correctly. btw, do you think this way is correct?

Comment: @MortezaAghili I would use `takeLatest` instead

Comment: @JoseAPL Can you tell me how? and why? Thanks.

Comment: @MortezaAghili imagine you have an auto-complete input which requests to an API every time the user changes the input, `takeLatest` will take the latest and kill the old ones

Comment: @JoseAPL Aha, you introduce takeLatest with an awesome example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is using TypeScript: when defining the reducer actions as an `enum`, make sure to replace the default value of each enum item to a string, e.g:

```js
// It will fail when using `Action.USER_SIGNIN` 
// because it's implicitly being set as the enum item position index (a number).
enum Action {
  USER_SIGNIN
}

// You need to define as string value instead:
enum Action {
  USER_SIGNIN = 'USER_SIGNIN'
}
```