# Error using redux saga, take(patternOrChannel): argument 8 is not valid channel or a valid pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to use redux saga library to capture some actions but I'm having this error when I run the app:

> index.js:2178 uncaught at rootSaga at rootSaga   at projectSaga   at
>   watchFetchRequest   at takeEvery   Error: take(patternOrChannel):
>   argument 8 is not valid channel or a valid pattern
>    at take (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84689:9)
>       at takeEvery (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85993:94)
>       at createTaskIterator (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85179:17)
>       at runForkEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85583:24)
>       at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85468:872)
>       at next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85348:9)
>       at proc (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85303:3)
>       at runForkEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85587:19)
>       at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85468:872)
>       at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85677:14
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at runAllEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85676:10)
>       at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85468:413)
>       at next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85348:9)
>       at proc (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85303:3)
>       at runForkEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85587:19)
>       at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85468:872)
>       at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85677:14
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at runAllEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85676:10)
>       at runEffect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85468:413)
>       at next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85348:9)
>       at proc (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85303:3)
>       at runSaga (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85858:76)
>       at Object../src/store/ReduxRoot.tsx (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95823:16)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:679:30)
>       at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89:20)
>       at Object../src/index.tsx (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:95325:75)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:679:30)
>       at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:89:20)
>       at Object.0 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96424:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:679:30)
>       at ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/arrayWithoutHoles.js.module.exports
>   (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:725:37)
>       at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:728:10

This is the saga code:

```
import { all, call, fork, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {  ActionType, Action, SearchCriteria } from '../model/types';
import { searchProjectsError, searchProjectsCompleted } from '../actions/projects';
import { API_URL } from '../../config';
// import axios from 'axios';

function callApi(method: string, url: string, path: string, data?: any) {
    return fetch(url  + path, {
      method,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json());
  }

// Here we use `redux-saga` to trigger actions asynchronously. `redux-saga` uses something called a
// "generator function", which you can read about here:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

function* handleFetch(action: Action<SearchCriteria>) {
  try {
    // To call async functions, use redux-saga's `call()`.
    const res = yield call(callApi, 'get', API_URL , '/api/DocumentLoader/GetProjects/', action.payload);

    if (res.error) {
      yield put(searchProjectsError(res.error));
    } else {
      yield put(searchProjectsCompleted(res));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      yield put(searchProjectsError(err.stack!));
    } else {
      yield put(searchProjectsError('An unknown error occured.'));
    }
  }
}

// This is our watcher function. We use `take*()` functions to watch Redux for a specific action
// type, and run our saga, for example the `handleFetch()` saga above.
function* watchFetchRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionType.SEARCH_PROJECTS, handleFetch); // I think the error is here
}

// We can also use `fork()` here to split our saga into multiple watchers.
function* projectSaga() {
  yield all([fork(watchFetchRequest)]);
}

export default projectSaga;
```

I already tried to find an answer here in SO, but the only I could find was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378562/redux-saga-get-data-from-action-returns-patternorchannel-is-undefined), but `ActionType` is been exported. I think the problem is with the parameter of `handleFetch` function

This is the action:

```
export function searchProjects(criterias: SearchCriteria): Action<SearchCriteria> {
    return {
        type: ActionType.SEARCH_PROJECTS,
        payload: criterias
    };
}
```

Another thing it could be is maybe I did something wrong at the time to compose the saga middleware:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

var middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, thunk, sagaMiddleware);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    middleware = composeWithDevTools(middleware);
}

// Here we use `redux-saga` to trigger actions asynchronously. `redux-saga` uses something called a
// "generator function", which you can read about here:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*
export function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([fork(projectSaga)]);
  }
// running the root saga, and return the store object.
 sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

I also tried removing the action parameter from `handleFetch` and the error is still happening

Comment: I have updated my answer, just have a look!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux-saga get data from action returns patternOrChannel is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378562/redux-saga-get-data-from-action-returns-patternorchannel-is-undefined)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found what was the error, the problem was the definition of `ActionType` enum. It was without assigning an string value for each action.

```
export const enum ActionType {

// Projects
SEARCH_PROJECT,
SEARCH_PROJECTS_COMPLETED,
SEARCH_PROJECTS_ERROR,

}
```

This fixed the problem:

```
export const enum ActionType {

// Projects
SEARCH_PROJECTS= '@@projects/SEARCH_PROJECTS',
SEARCH_PROJECTS_COMPLETED= '@@projects/SEARCH_PROJECTS_COMPLETED',
SEARCH_PROJECTS_ERROR= '@@projects/SEARCH_PROJECTS_ERROR',

}
```

Comment: In general, the error is the result of not assigning the action constant to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible error could be this:

Check whether you have imported the { ActionType } object here, from the models file where you have defined your constants.

```
export function searchProjects(criterias: SearchCriteria): 
    Action<SearchCriteria> {
    return {
        type: ActionType.SEARCH_PROJECTS,
        payload: criterias
    };
}
```

Comment: but that is not what I'm doing in the `watchFetchRequest` function?

Comment: Sorry, thats a mistake on my part. I did not notice that part of the code. I will try to come up with the solution.

Comment: About your update, take a look the line that shows the import: `import {  ActionType, Action, SearchCriteria } from '../model/types';`

Comment: you have to import the ActionType in the file where you have the searchProjects action as well. The ActionType has to be imported in both files.

Comment: I'm doing also that, I'm using typescript, If were an error of that kind, typescript would let me know

Comment: Glad to help! Can I know what the issue was?

Comment: Take a look my answer